# GCC 4.7.3 uninstall

Tags: gcc

How can i uninstall `GCC 4.7.3` and install `GCC 4.5`? I want to install 4.5 because otherwise my `BF 1942` wont open with wine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please expand your question by including details about what Wine needs to run BF1942. Why do you believe having GCC 4.5 installed will help? Can you give a link to a source for this? Note that having GCC 4.5 *installed* will not cause the version of Wine you have installed to be *built* with GCC 4.5, nor will it generally cause the version of Wine you have installed to use different libraries (though that is possible). This problem probably can be solved but we'll most likely need more information to give a comprehensive answer. Also, what version of Ubuntu do you use?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to install it and it will update the older version with the newer files.

If you installed the programme with `sudo apt-get install <programme>` you could use `sudo apt-get purge <programme>`